# AngularJS dynamic array in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS ng-repeat to populate a select html object. 
Each category object has a list of subcategories which is computed dynamically depending on the main category that is selected from the first select. These subcategories are themselves shown in another select.

The code is similar to the following

```
    <div>
        <select>
            <option ng-value="sk.id" ng-repeat="sk in skills" ng-bind-html="sk.name"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="cat in mainCategories">
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option ng-value="subcat.id" ng-repeat="subcat in cat.allsubcategories" ng-bind-html="subcat.name" ></option> 
               </select>
            </div>
    </div>
```

When a skill is selected from the first select (ng-repeat="sk in skill")
a new category is created and the function addMainCategory (see below) is called. When creating the category, an ajax action is called to fetch its subcategories. Afterwards, the main category and its subcategories array are pushed to the angular scope. The javascript code is the following:

```
var addMainCategory = function(idCat, nameCat, parent, color){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
         var newMainCat = {"id": idCat, "name": nameCat, "allsubcategories":[]};
         $.ajax('?r=user/subcategory&id='+idCat).done(function(data) {

         var cat_parse = JSON.parse(data);
         for (var i=0; i< cat_parse.length; i++) {
            newMainCat.allsubcategories.push({"id":cat_parse[i].id, "name":cat_parse[i].name});
        }
    });
    $scope.mainCategories.push(newMainCat);
});
```

However, despite the main category is correctly shown, its subcategories (variable "allsubcategories") are not updated on the select, i.e. no subcat are shown inside the nested select, even if the variable are correct (checked with firebug).
Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: `$scope.mainCategories.push(newMainCat);` <-- See this newMainCat. It does not exist here.

Comment: It's probably because angular runs the `apply()` immediately after your `ajax()` call without waiting for it to finish. Why not use `$http` instead of ajax so you don't have to worry about these types of async issues?